# How enforce GCC to decorate name with leading underline?

Tags: gcc, dllexport, name-mangling

I compile DLL with JNI Java interface functions.
In header file I have:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class net_sf_junace_UnACE */

#ifndef _Included_net_sf_junace_UnACE
#define _Included_net_sf_junace_UnACE
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_net_sf_junace_UnACE_nativeACEList
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject, jstring, jobject);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

MS Visual C++ decorated name is:
_Java_net_sf_junace_UnACE_nativeACEList@20

GCC:
Java_net_sf_junace_UnACE_nativeACEList@20

JNI requires leading underscore. How enforce GCC to generate it?
-fleading-underscore  not helps, why?